# Printing in a for-loop alters list type?

Tags: loops, printing, readlines

Why wouldn't this print me the lines from the txt file?

```
f = open("myflie.txt", "r")

for x in range(len(f.readlines())):
    print(x, f.readlines()[x])

f.close()
```

it gives me the

> IndexError: list index out of range ???

If I put an out-of-loop print command such as:

```
print(f.readlines()[0])
```

it will normally print the very first line of the file. It will repeat the same if I keep changing the [i] index, but if I put the print line inside the loop, then it gives me the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `readlines()` rolls the file descriptor forward to its very end.

So calling `readlines()` again without first rewinding the file descriptor returns an empty array.

Comment: how do i rewind?

Comment: @ZlatkoCherepnalkoski: Why not simply save it into `lines = readlines()` and then iterate `lines`???

Comment: name[k] = lines[i][len(lines[i])-5:]
This line gives me en error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
Why wouldn;t it release the last part of he string starting from the 5th place?

Comment: got it ... append is the appropriate method, not "="